# 2Dimensional Array of Class objects gives error: Null Reference Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have been away from coding for a while, trying to get a simple project going to get my hand back in, and I am stuck.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Dungeon : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Tile[,] map = new Tile[40, 40];

    void Start() {
        for (int y = 0; y < 40; y++) {
           for (int x = 0; x < 40; x++){
                map[x, y].ceiling = 0;
                map[x, y].northWall = 0;
                map[x, y].westWall = 0;
                map[x, y].floor = 0;
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

It wont run, gives me an error that says: "NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

I should mention, the Tile class is just a holder for ceiling, northWall, westWall, and floor. They are all integers and I am relying on the implied constructor. here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Tile : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int ceiling { get; set; }
    public int northWall { get; set; }
    public int westWall { get; set; }
    public int floor { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Tile` is of type `MonoBehaviour`! `MonoBehaviours` can not be created like normal classed but only by adding them using `AddComponent` to a certain `GameObject`; they can not exist without being attached to a `GameObject`.

Therefore your line

```
public Tile[,] map = new Tile[40, 40];
```

actually does **not** create a filled array with instances with default values but instead creates a 2-dimensional array filled with `null` placeholders for `Tile` **refeences**, not instances.

I guess what you want instead is:

**Tile**

```
// use this tag to make it 
// serializable and e.g. visiable in the inspector
[System.Serializable]
public class Tile
{
    // use fields instead of properties 
    // since also properties are not serialzed
    public int ceiling;
    public int northWall;
    public int westWall;
    public int floor;
}
```

and

```
public class Dungeon : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Tile[,] map = new Tile[40, 40];

    private void Start() 
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 40; y++) 
        {
           for (int x = 0; x < 40; x++)
           {
                // For simple types like e.g. int, string etc there are default values
                // so the array would be filled with those values.
                // However your class Tile has the default value null
                // So you have to create Tile instances using the default constructor like
                map[x, y] = new Tile();

                // And than optionally give it values
                // though they will be 0 by default of course
                map[x, y].ceiling = 0;
                map[x, y].northWall = 0;
                map[x, y].westWall = 0;
                map[x, y].floor = 0;

                // or alternatively
                map[x, y] = new Tile()
                    {
                        ceiling = 0,
                        northWall = 0,
                        westWall = 0,
                        floor = 0
                    };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

But I personally would always prefer having a proper constructor and field names (public => PascalCase)

```
[System.Serializable]
public class Tile
{
    public int Ceiling ;
    public int NorthWall;
    public int WestWall;
    public int Floor;

    public Tile(int ceiling, int northWall, int westWall, int floor)
    {
        Ceiling = ceiling;
        NorthWall = northWall;
        WestWall = westWall;
        Floor = floor;
    }
}
```

and using

```
public class Dungeon : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Tile[,] map = new Tile[40, 40];

    private void Start() 
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 40; y++) 
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 40; x++)
            {
                Tile[x, y] = new Tile(0,0,0,0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: At creation, fields of class objects are always assigned the type's default value (`default(T)`). Therefore all the `int` fields will be `0` automatically.

Comment: Its an example .. having a constructor later allows more flexibility like `new Tile(1,2,3,4)` etc

Answer (score 0):

derHugo led me the answer in the time it took to make myself peanut butter toast. Way to go derHugo!

Here is my Tile class. It didn't need all the MonoBehavior stuff, and I added a constructor as suggested:

```
public class Tile
{
    public int ceiling { get; set; }
    public int northWall { get; set; }
    public int westWall { get; set; }
    public int floor { get; set; }

    public Tile(int c, int n, int w, int f)
    {
        ceiling = c;
        northWall = n;
        westWall = w;
        floor = f;
    }
}
```

Here is the function that uses the Tile class:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Dungeon : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Tile[,] map = new Tile[40, 40];

void Start()
{
    for (int y = 0; y < 40; y++) {
       for (int x = 0; x < 40; x++){
            map[x, y] = new Tile(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now it runs!

Comment: You should accept an answer as solution rather than posting the same solution as answer as well. I still would prefer my way in order to have the `Tile` and it's data serialized -> also visible in the inspector